# How to share folder between virtual box ubuntu and host windows?

Tags: virtualbox, sharing

I have been using ubuntu in virtual box. Now i need to copy a folder from windows to the VM ubuntu.
In virtual box i have selected the folder in share folder option but cant figure out how to access in virtual box ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the guest OS.
Once booted, click Devices | Insert Guest Additions CD
When prompted, click Run.
Type your user password and click Authenticate.
Allow the installation to complete.
When prompted, hit the Enter key on your keyboard.
One last step is to add your user to the vboxsf group using this command:

sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)

With the guest still booted, click Devices | Shared Folders | Shared Folder Settings. In this new window, you'll create a new Transient Folder that can be seen by the hist OS.

Mount the shared folder in the guest od with the command sudo mount -t vboxsf Public ~/Public. Change the name of the folder accordingly. This should be visible in the host OS.

Source: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-share-folders-between-guest-and-host-in-virtualbox/